# Android Media Player not playing after Stopping once

Tags: android, media-player

Media Player is starting and playing stream fine. But if I press stop once, I cannot play that again. App is closed. Code is here

```
Button StartStop;
final MediaPlayer MyRadio = new MediaPlayer();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    StartStop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.StartStop);

    StartStop.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            if (MyRadio.isPlaying()){
                MyRadio.stop();
                MyRadio.release();
                StartStop.setText("Start");
            } else {
                PrepareRadio("http://220.247.162.146:7170/");
                MyRadio.start();
                StartStop.setText("Stop");
            }

        }
    });

}

public void PrepareRadio(String Source){
    try {
        MyRadio.reset();
        MyRadio.setDataSource(Source);
        MyRadio.prepare();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I need your advice to solve this.

Comment: I've replaced MyRadio.release() with MyRadio.reset() and working fine now. Thanks guys for giving your valuable time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize your `MediaPlayer` class on `onCreate()` method.

```
 final MediaPlayer MyRadio;


 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

  MyRadio = new MediaPlayer();

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Move `MyRadio.release();` and put it in `onDestroy` in your Activity